# Web2py - how to create a group "manager" using appadmin

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, web2py, web2py-modules

I'm going through [Web2py book documentation](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/03/overview#Simple-examples) because i'm new to it and i can't find any better tutorial anywhere (recommendations are welcomed). While going through the overview section, i got to an instruction that says

> Using appadmin create a group "manager" and make some users members of the group.

I've been trying to figure out how to do this for the past few hours and still no success. I can't find any interface in the app admin for creating groups. I tried [this plugin manager](https://github.com/zvolsky/plugin_manage_groups) for managing groups and i was still getting errors. All suggestions are welcomed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Authorization](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/09/access-control#Authorization) section of the Access Control chapter -- as noted there, you can use the **appadmin** interface (described [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/03/overview#An-image-blog)) or add groups and members programmatically.

To access appadmin, just go to `/yourapp/appadmin` (if you are not logged into the `/admin` app, you will be prompted to do so).

To add a new Auth group/role, add a new record to the `db.auth_group` table in appadmin. To add a new member to that group, add a new record to `db.auth_membership`, which links records from `db.auth_user` and `db.auth_group`.

You can also add groups and members programmatically, either via app code or a web2py shell (which can be started via `python web2py.py -S yourapp -M`, as described [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Command-line-options)). Add groups with `auth.add_group` and members with `auth.add_membership` (as documented at the link above).

Comment: Thanks so much. i was defining the db variable again at the end of the db.py file so only the tables i defined was getting created. the once the came by default wasn't created and was not desplaying in the appadmin. Thanks very much for the help